# How to align side by side 2 differents component in angular with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

How can I align 2 different Component side by side using flexbox ?

I have my 1st component "nav-menu" and the 2nd "homepage" I would like it to be side by side.

**homepage.component.html**

```
    <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img src="https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/amado/img/product-img/pro-big-1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I gave a width to my container

**homepage.component.css**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
}

div.container>div {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

img {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**nav-menu.component.html**

```
    <h1>Furniture</h1>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul clas="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I gave a width to my nav

**nav-menu.component.css**

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

nav {
    width: 40%;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: white;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 10px;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #FFA500;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```

whats the next step ?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to wrap your both components in a `flex`

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-grow: grow">
  <app-component-1></app-component-1>
  <app-component-2></app-component-2>
</div>
```